# TypeError: data type "category" not understood, while looping through the columns in the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, user-defined-types

```
data.info()
```

[DataTypes info of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIkhH.png)

```
for col in data.columns:
    if data[col].dtype == "category":
        print(data[col].value_counts())
        print("\n\n")
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: data type "category" not understood
```

Is there any other way to find the same?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
for col in data.select_dtypes('category'):
    print(data[col].value_counts(), end='\n\n')
```